# Query with added columns as partition

Tags: mysql, sql, partition

I have a set of results in a `results` table. Each result has `f_player1` and `f_player2`... a player can be in either column over different results.

I'm trying to group the players together as rows and then check the count of each player per week. There is a column in results called `f_week`, an `INT` value increasing after each week. How can I have the count for each player in rows and then each week as the columns?

My query so far:

```
SELECT player,
SUM(CASE WHEN x.f_week=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_1_count
FROM (
    (SELECT f_player1 AS player, f_week, f_id, f_datetime FROM results)
    UNION
    (SELECT f_player2 AS player, f_week, f_id, f_datetime FROM results)
    ) x INNER JOIN sim_quotes ON sim_quotes.f_id=x.f_id
    GROUP BY player ORDER BY player
```

So I have grouped by players but I need to partition also by f_week and then somehow have each week count as a column. The weeks will increase with time so it's not a static query.. the number of columns should increase with time.

Expected output:

```
player   |     week_1 |      week_2     |    week_3    | ....

player_x |       2              6              3
player_y |       5              1              0  
player_z |       3              10             2
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Sample data would really help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can unpivot the data using `union all` and then aggregate:

```
select player,
       sum(f_week = 1) then week_1,
       sum(f_week = 2) then week_2,
       sum(f_week = 3) then week_3,
       . . . 
from ((select f_player1 as player, f_week
       from results
      ) union all
      (select f_player2 as player, f_week
       from results
      ) 
     ) pw
group by player;
```

If you need this for an indeterminate number of weeks, then you will need to use dynamic SQL to construct the conditional aggregation logic.